# JQuery.each printing values backwards

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, object

I am using JQuery to retrieve an object and use it to point to images at a folder and print it into a slider.

The problem is that I am getting the images backwards and I don't understand why, since when I log the values it is shown in the correct order.

This is my object:

```
let mainSliderData

function returnData(){
    mainSliderData = {
        img1: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider.gif',
        img2: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider1.png',
        img3: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider3.png',
        img4: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider4.jpg',
        img5: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider5.jpg',
        img6: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider6.jpg',
        img7: '../vendors/img/slide1/slider7.jpg',
    }

    return mainSliderData
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript( "../../data/mainSliderData.js", function( data ) {

        $.each(returnData(), (index, value) => {

            $('<div></div>').css("background-image", `url(${value})`).addClass('slider__img slide--js').prependTo('#test')

            console.log(value)
        })

    }) .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log('error:')
        console.log(exception)
    })
})
```

Console:

[image]

Slider:

[image]

As can be seen, the original order is `img1 to img7`, but the slider is receiveing `img7 to img1`.

This is a problem, since the order is very important to my project.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.prependTo('#test')`, I think you'd need to use `.appendTo('#test')`.